# Cargar una nueva URL dependiendo de condición React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

Dada una condición, si es cierta, ¿cómo es posible cargar una URL específica?

```
 const completarRegistro =()=>{
    if(codigo===codigo_agregado){
       /*Cargar una URL específica */
    }
    else{
      setCount(6);
    }
  }
```

En los botones se usa href = "/url". Pero ¿qué debería usar en una función?

Lo que he intentado es:

```
 const completarRegistro =()=>{
    if(codigo===codigo_agregado){
 const win = window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Completarinfo/", '_blank');
  if (win != null) {
    win.focus();
  }        }
    else{
      setCount(6);
    }
  }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: pero donde se encuentra esa `URL` , es `react-router` o verlo via `iframe`

Comment: a que te refieres con cargar?

Comment: tengo por ejemplo una url que es /registro. Si yo desde una url por ejemplo /home, quiero ir a /registro a través de una función ¿cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: lo que he intentado es:      const win = window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Completarinfo/", '_blank');
      if (win != null) {
        win.focus();
      }

Comment: `window.location="nuevaDireccion"` eso deberia de servir

Comment: Gracias. Pero lo que necesito es cargar la url en la misma pestaña y me abre otra pestaña